# Proof of limit inequality

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

> Prove that for any sequence $\{x_n\}$ of positive real numbers
>   $$\lim\text{sup}\sqrt[n]{x_n}\leq \lim\text{sup}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}.$$

My attempt:

Let $A = \lim\text{sup}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$. Suppose $A<\infty$ and choose $\epsilon >0$, then $\exists$ an integer $N$ so that $N\le n \implies \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\le \epsilon$. But I do not know how to proceed in finishing the proof?

Comment: No, that's wrong.  The conclusion could be $\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \le A + \epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if $x_{n+1}/x_n \le B$ for $n \ge N$, then $x_n \le x_N B^{n-N}$ for $n \ge N$.  What does that tell you about $x_n^{1/n}$?

Comment: Since $x_n \le x_N B^{n-N}$ then $x_n^{1/n}\le x_n \le x_N B^{n-N}$? Correct?

Comment: No, not correct.  Take the $1/n$ power of both sides.

Comment: Hmm, can you elaborate further please?

Comment: From $x_n \le x_N B^{n-N}$ you get
$x_n^{1/n} \le (x_N B^{-N})^{1/n} B$.  The  right side has limit $B$ as $n \to \infty$.